# how to do Merge Sequential in tf.keras get "A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs"

Tags: merge, tf.keras, sequential

I am trying to merge in tf.keras . What is the equivalent.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([sentrnn, qrnn]))
```

getting following exception
A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs

trying to convert this code I found on one of the sites

```
model.add(Merge([sentrnn, qrnn], mode='concat'))
model.add(Merge([sentrnn, qrnn], mode='sum'))


sentrnn = Sequential()
sentrnn.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE, mask_zero=True))
sentrnn.add(RNN(SENT_HIDDEN_SIZE, return_sequences=False))
sentrnn.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE, input_length=story_maxlen, mask_zero=True))
sentrnn.add(Dropout(0.3))

qrnn = Sequential()
qrnn.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE))
qrnn.add(RNN(QUERY_HIDDEN_SIZE, return_sequences=False))
qrnn.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE, input_length=query_maxlen))
qrnn.add(Dropout(0.3))
qrnn.add(RNN(EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE, return_sequences=False))
qrnn.add(RepeatVector(story_maxlen))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([sentrnn, qrnn], mode='concat'))
model.add(Merge([sentrnn, qrnn], mode='sum'))
model.add(RNN(EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your actual question is.

Comment: When I try to merge two Sequential Models . I get the following error ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs. I am trying to convert an example I found ( complete original code https://github.com/ijcnlp2017anonsubmission/Dilton-word-problem-solver/blob/master/web/model1.py) which is using older version of keras to tensorflow.keras (v2.3.0)

Comment: It seems that there are issues when using a Concatenate layer with the Sequential models. Is there any specific reason why you do not use the Functional API? I would recommend using it.

Comment: thanks for responding . Appreciate it. I am new to all this. Will read up on Functional API and give it a try.